# cordova application for getting parameter from the app url

Tags: cordova, google-play

I Am trying to install "https://github.com/florentvaldelievre/virtualartifacts-webintent" in my cordova application for getting parameter from the app url.

```
 window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
   alert(url);
   });


**But, the url will return 2 params as utm_source and utm_medium.**

I am using the referral link like: "TestApp://https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=test.product&referral_code=testrefer"

 AndroidManifest.xml write the following:
         <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="TestApp" />
            </intent-filter>

I don't get the "referral_code" parameter from the URL. 

Any one please help me....
```

Answer (score 1):

To build a referrer URL, use the [Google Play URL Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) or be aware of the [campaign parameters documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#campaign-params)

Comment: Here "referral_code" is my custom parameter. I don't get that parameter in getUri() response. That is my issue

Comment: Google Play won't pass on any custom parameters. Only the ones listed.